# Error while installing SciPy through pip on windows, having metadata error

Tags: python, pip, scipy, metadata

## **   I got an output of this log:  **

Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [37 lines of output]
+ meson setup --prefix=c:\users\ohadr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32 C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b.mesonpy-d59ejxu_\build --native-file=C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.3
Source dir: C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b
Build dir: C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b.mesonpy-d59ejxu_\build
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.10.1
Activating VS 17.0.4
C compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.30.30706 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30706 for x64")
C linker for the host machine: link link 14.30.30706.0
C++ compiler for the host machine: cl (msvc 19.30.30706 "Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.30.30706 for x64")
C++ linker for the host machine: link link 14.30.30706.0
Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: NO
Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types: NO
Library m found: NO

```
  ..\..\meson.build:63:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['ifort'], ['gfortran'], ['flang'], ['pgfortran'], ['g95']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `ifort --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `ifort -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `flang -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgfortran --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgfortran -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `g95 --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `g95 -V` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\ohadr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0zbjnob0\scipy_1ba51c155259474da69bcd9990585d9b\.mesonpy-d59ejxu_\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

**I got Python 3.8, and also pip, wheel and setuptools up-to-date. Also NumPy is installed
How can I fix that and install SciPy?, should I install something else?
(I`m using VSC)**

Answer (score -1):

You need a newer version of python, scipy only supports python 3.9+ https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#data

Comment: `scipy` 1.10.1 supports Python 3.8: https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.10.1/#data

Comment: My mistake I was looking at the wrong version. `scipy` 1.10.1 does support 3.8 on windows for 64-bit version of python interpreter. Looking at this line on your error `prefix=c:\users\ohadr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32` it looks like you have 32-bit python installed, so it can't use the wheel and is trying to build from source. Are you running a 64-bit machine and can you install 64-bit python?

Comment: My advice is to [edit] the answer and put everything there.

Comment: OP is on a 64 bit machine (`Host machine cpu family: x86_64 Host machine cpu: x86_64`), but for some reason is running a 32 bit interpreter.